# I have json result. It has a data property searchedSchools. how to assign its values to schoolsO: Observable<SchoolDetailModel[]> in subscribe method

Tags: angular

```
export class SchoolIndexComponent implements OnInit {

public schoolsO: Observable<SchoolDetailModel[]>;

constructor(private router: Router, private schoolService: 
SchoolServiceService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.loadSchools();
}

private loadSchools() {
 this.schoolService.getSchools()
   .subscribe((data: Observable<SchoolDetailModel[]>) => {
     this.schoolsO = data;

  });
}
```

{"status":0,"message":"Success","data":{"searchedSchools":[{"schoolId":1,"schoolName":"Ryan International Amritsar","brand":"Ryan","state":{"stateId":2,"stateName":"Punjab","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"stateId":2,"city":{"cityId":1,"stateId":2,"cityName":"Amritsar","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"cityId":1,"isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-10-12T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-10-12T00:00:00"},{"schoolId":2,"schoolName":"Ryan International Gurgaon","brand":"Ryan","state":{"stateId":3,"stateName":"Haryana","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"stateId":3,"city":{"cityId":5,"stateId":3,"cityName":"Gurgaon","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"cityId":5,"isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-10-12T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-10-12T00:00:00"},{"schoolId":3,"schoolName":"Ryan International Pune","brand":"Ryan","state":{"stateId":7,"stateName":"Maharastra","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"stateId":7,"city":{"cityId":18,"stateId":7,"cityName":"Pune","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"cityId":18,"isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-10-12T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-10-12T00:00:00"},{"schoolId":4,"schoolName":"Ryan International Jaipur","brand":"Ryan","state":{"stateId":5,"stateName":"Rajasthan","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"stateId":5,"city":{"cityId":10,"stateId":5,"cityName":"Jaipur","isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-12-23T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-12-23T00:00:00"},"cityId":10,"isDirty":false,"dateCreated":"2018-10-12T00:00:00","dateModified":"2018-10-12T00:00:00"}]}}

Answer (score 0):

try this to assign response value to the parameter

`.subscribe((data) => {
this.schoolsO = data;
}`